# Does assigning a new Box to an existing variable leak memory or not?

Tags: memory-management, rust

I wrote some Rust to examine how to return a `Box<T>` for later use which did what I thought, but then I wrote something I expected to be rejected by the compiler only to find it compiled and ran. It appears to leak memory:

```
fn main() {
    //  test data
    let v: i32 = 5;
    let w: i32 = 11;
    let x: i32 = 32;

    let mut p: Box<i32> = box_this(v);
    println!("{:p} contains {}", p, p);

    //  mutate contents of p (*p)
    *p += w;
    println!("{:p} contains {}", p, p);

    //  Make p point to something else.  Does the compiler know to free what p formerly pointed to??
    p = box_this(x);
    println!("{:p} contains {}", p, p);
}

fn box_this(val: i32) -> Box<i32> {
    Box::<i32>::new(val)
}
```

output:

```
0x55c025781c00 contains 5
0x55c025781c00 contains 16  // what happens to this allocation?
0x55c025781d70 contains 32
```

When `p = box_this(x)` executes, does the compiler know to drop the allocation of `Ox....1c00` as now nothing points to that, or does this actually orphan the chunk at that location? It would orphan if this was C and no `free(p)` was executed before a new `p = malloc(...)`.

I realize this is unlikely to occur in a real program, because `let p = box_this(some_val)` would almost certainly be in the scope of a loop, and would dropped at the end of the loop.

Comment: If you speak C++, you can think of `Box<T>` as the Rust equivalent of `std::unique_ptr<T>`. Just as assigning a different pointer to a `unique_ptr` won't leak in C++, neither will assigning a different box in Rust.

Comment: Though the mechanisms how this works are very different in C++ and Rust. In C++, you need to explicitly implement `operator=()` to release the memory of the old pointer before assigning, in addition to implementing a destructor that also realeases the memory. In Rust, you only implement the `Drop` trait, and the compiler figures out all the places where it needs to be called, including upon reassignment.

Comment: It's rather difficult to _accidentally_ leak memory in Rust.

Comment: Thanks all, especially @Shepmaster for answer in the other post, that totally explains what is happening.